# Calendar Function Call not working invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an error message when trying to pass a function into a calendar component - not sure how I'm meant to make this specific function call to change the data being fetched?

This is the calendar component,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
    
export default function DateRange({startDate,endDate,handleChange})  {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selectsRange={true}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={handleChange}
      withPortal
    />
  );
};
```

This is the file that has the function i want to handleChange with,

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import { useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { apiRequest } from "../../../util/util";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import groupBy from "lodash/groupBy";
// import get from "lodash/get";



export default function useAnalytics() {
  
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([d.getTime(), Date.now()]);
  const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;

      
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setDateRange(e)
    const { data: sentimentData } = useSWR(
      `xx/xx/xxx-xx-xx?startTime=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`,
      fetchSentiment
    );
    return sentimentData
 }

  

  const { data: sentimentData } = useSWR(
    `xx/xx/xx-xx-xx?startTime=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`,
    fetchSentiment
  );

  return {
    sentimentData,
   
    handleChange,
    setDateRange,
    startDate,
    endDate,
  };
}
```

This get's passed into another function here,

```
import useAnalytics from './useAnalytics.js'
export default function Analytics() {
  const {
    sentimentData,
   
    handleChange,
    startDate,
     endDate
  } = useAnalytics();
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      
      <div>
        Calendar
      <DateRange  handleChange = {handleChange} startDate = {startDate} endDate = {endDate} />
      </div>
      ....
  );
}
```

When it calls the function I receive an invalid hook call error.

I want to be able to have the date change, and then send a query to change the data available in the parent function. Not sure where I'm going wrong with this current setup?

#### Update

Below worked really well! Now the date being used for the query is in the wrong format though,

Trying this code at the moment,

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setDateRange(e);
    setDateRange(Date(dateRange[0]).getTime(),Date(dateRange[1].getTime()))
  };
```

which isn't working as the function getTime won't convert the value to anything.

This is the returned values from the calendar,

```
console.log("type of data: ",typeof startDate,"start Date: ", startDate,"EndDate: ", endDate)

type of data:  object start Date:  Mon Aug 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time) EndDate:  Wed Aug 18 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: It's `useSWR` and where do you get `startDate` and `endDate` in `useAnalytics` from?

Comment: StartDate and endDate I had edited out, but it's above

Comment: useSWR is a next.js function to perform fetch (the fetch function works properly)

Comment: I put my answer down below, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`useSWR` is a hook and you [should not call it inside a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)**

You could put it right on top of your function:

```
export default function useAnalytics() {
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([d.getTime(), Date.now()]);
  const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;

  const { data: sentimentData } = useSWR(
    `xx/xx/xxx-xx-xx?startTime=${startDate}&endTime=${endDate}`,
    fetchSentiment
  );
//...Rest of your function
```

And remove it from your `handleChange`:

```
const handleChange = e => {
  setDateRange(e);
  return sentimentData;
};
```

Comment: Got the same error sadly, invalid hook call eugh

Comment: Nah, Realized I was wrong, updating the answer

Comment: removed return sentimentData, as that should be provided through the rest of the function I think

Comment: You can just put it inside the function body, it will fetch every time state change, try it out, mate

Comment: The issue with this, is it doesn't fetch the dates when this happens properly for some reason, i'll check what data type is going through though

Comment: Yeah, might be some issue with state change? It should be fetched again if the state change and the function run over again.

Comment: Yeah good point - I think the data type is wrong that's being returned hrm, will try fix

Comment: Yeah, let me know if I can help.

Comment: I'll add the issue into the question above, need to convert the dates into a unix timestamp

Comment: Hmm. I don't have knowledge on that unfortunately

Comment: I worked out the solution as well. Thanks dude helps a lot!